# Create list<objects> in C#

Tags: c#, list, class

I am trying to create a class like this:

```
public class person
{
    public string name { get; set;}
    public int age  { get; set;}
}
```

and create a class which is basically a list of the class above:

```
public class PersonList : List<person>
{
    public PersonList()
    { 
    }

    public int getAge(string name)
    { 
        foreach( string s n this)
        {
            if ( s == name)
                return age;
        }
    }
```

My goal is to have simple function named **GetAge()** so I get the the age by name of any *person* object in my list.
I know it is possible to just create a list, but I want a modular code.

Comment: And what problem do you have ? The code seems ok, should work

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Your loop in the getAge can't be iterated as string.  The type in the list isn't a string, its person.

Comment: There are easier/more elegant ways to get the property of a list item using linq

Comment: What you're apparently trying to do is `return this.FirstOrDefault(a=> a.name == name)?.age ?? 0;`

Comment: @Felype 0 is not an ideal return type in case of null as a baby will have age 0. A negative number is better.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I did not consider. Alternatively the return value could be a nullable int, or that function could throw an exception when name is not found.

Comment: [Don't inherit from `List<T>`!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

Comment: @Scott. Your link doesn't say never inherit from list, it says only inherit from list if the inherited object actually is a list, which it is in this case.

Comment: And so? What do you need?

Answer (score 2):

```
public int getAge(string name)
{ 
     return this.First(x=>x.name==name).age;       
}
```

This will throw an error if person not found.

To return -1 when person is not found:

```
public int getAge(string name)
{ 
     return this.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.name==name)?.age??-1;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must consider that a **name can be repeated in a list** so you arbitrarily would be getting the first one, in the sample below you have two options.

```
public class person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
    }
    public class PersonList : List<person>
    {
        public int getAge(string name)
        {
            return this.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == name)?.age ?? -1;
        }
        public int[] getAge2(string name)
        {
            return this.Where(x => x.name == name).Select(x=>x.age).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

And you will get a list of ages in case the name is repeated, console code below

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PersonList listOfPerson = new PersonList();
            listOfPerson.Add(new person() { age = 25, name = "jhon" });
            listOfPerson.Add(new person() { age = 26, name = "jhon" });
            listOfPerson.Add(new person() { age = 21, name = "homer" });
            listOfPerson.Add(new person() { age = 22, name = "bill" });
            listOfPerson.Add(new person() { age = 27, name = "jhon" });
            listOfPerson.Add(new person() { age = 22, name = "andrew" });

            foreach (var item in listOfPerson.getAge2("jhond"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```